# Count number of unique combinations with a twist

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We have some balls that are placed in multiple rows.
We need to count all possible combinations of balls from different rows, knowing that there are some incompatibilities between them, i.e. two balls cannot co-exist within a single combination.

Here is a simple example:

[image: Visualization of the described problem]

We have the following setup:
$$
Balls = \{ \{ A1, A2, A3 \}, \{ B1, B2 \}, \{ C1, C2, C3 \}, \{ D1, D2, D3 \} \} \\
Constraints = \{ \langle A2, C2 \rangle, \langle B1, D1 \rangle, \langle B2, D1 \rangle, \langle C3, D3 \rangle \}
$$

I tried implementing various concepts from my probability classes - I observe each pair from the constraints multitude as a separate event (let's note it as $P(Ball1 \leftrightarrow Ball2)$ for clarity). I found out that I can calculate the number of combinations that should be excluded from the total count by using the probability of the union of all constraint events, i.e. $P(A2 \leftrightarrow C2 \cup B1 \leftrightarrow D1 \cup B2 \leftrightarrow D1 \cup C3 \leftrightarrow D3)$.
However, I could not manage to optimize the computation process as the events (in most cases) are **not** independent - this means that the De Morgan's Laws are not applicable.

I need to construct a computer algorithm that should be as efficient as possible. I wonder if I am missing something or this is just one of those hardly-ever-solvable problems and I should better try to find another approach?

Comment: How many balls are there per combination, or can all compatible balls be put it into a combination?

Comment: There must be only one ball from each row. Some example combinations would be $\{ \langle A1, B1, C1, D2 \rangle, \langle A1, B1, C1, D3 \rangle, \langle A1, B1, C2, D2 \rangle \}$ but not $\{ \langle A1, B1, C1, D1 \rangle, \langle A1, B1, C2, D1 \rangle \}$ because $B1$ and $D1$ are incompatible.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is [#P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%99%AFP)-complete, which is at least as hard as NP, and probably much harder.

To see this, it's easy to reduce #SAT (problem "how many variable assignments satisfy given CNF") to your problem: add a row for each clause, and say that literals $x$ and $\neg x$ are incompatible, while all other are compatible. Then combination of balls corresponds to satisfying assignment.